# Allow requests to SF endpoints only from several ec2 instances

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a public API running on EC2 instance (through AWS ELB) built with Symfony3. However, I have several background tasks which have to consume this API but only on dedicated endpoints. I have to ensure that it is only the workers that consume these endpoints.

I was wondering how can I implement such a structure with AWS. I'm looking at API gateway, VPCs, but I'm kind of lost.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If both the API server and the API consumers are running on EC2 instances, then you can easily configure the security group assigned to your API server to restrict access to only those API consumer instances. Just create a rule in the security group that opens the inbound port for your API, and use the security group(s) assigned to your API consumer instances as the source.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to try that way. So I have to open the 443 port (for the public API) and restrict another port (eg. 8080) just for internal calls?

Comment: You have both a public API, and a separate private API on the same server?

Comment: Yes. I use SF3 routing for separate both. In fact, I'd like to keep the same version of app for both apps. Should I split them into 2 separate instances ?